# list: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, libstdc++

I'm trying to cross port a big autotools project to Android, but I'm having some issues with the NDK configuration (I guess). When I run the configure script, everything goes well until I reach a point where the C++ Standard Template Library support is checked. Then configure: error: C++ Standard Template Libary unsupported shows up.

Taking a closer look into the config.log I found

```
/home/user/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c  --sysroot=/home/user/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG conftest.cpp >&5

conftest.cpp:30:16: fatal error: list: No such file or directory
 #include <list>
```

These are the values for the environment variables

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/user/android-ndk-r10e
export SYS_ROOT=/home/user/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
export ANDROID_EABI=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
export ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/toolchains/${ANDROID_EABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export CC="$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
export CXX="$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYS_ROOT}"
export LDFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYS_ROOT}"
export CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=${SYS_ROOT}"
```

I guess that I'm missing some includes or some libraries on the command (Although they should be in the sysroot folder).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/intl/es/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

The C++ Standard Template Library is not included in the pre-built toolchain. You need to install a standalone toolchain so a stl implementation is copied into the platform. See the Advanced Method section of the link above to solve it.